# Как взять из БД дату и сравнить ее с текущей датой

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql

Есть база данных, условно `data_date`, в ней есть таблица `users` в которой есть столбец `close_date` в данной БД значения `date` в формате `2022-10-10`.

Мне нужно взять данную дату из БД и сравнить ее с текущей, если текущая меньше, то разрешить дальнейшие действия

пробовал вот так, но возвращает None

```py
current_date = datetime.now().date()
ends_date = cursor.execute(f"SELECT close_date FROM users WHERE close_date = ?", [chat_id]).fetchone()
if current_date <= close_date:
    pass
```

Comment: *пробовал вот так* Похоже, пробовал не думая. Иначе никак не объяснить попытку сравнения даты с идентификатором чата.

Comment: Да, я пока пробовал понял что [chat_id] здесь совсем не к месту, однако правильного решения еще не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exists = cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id, close_date FROM id_api WHERE user_id = ? and close_date >= current_date", [chat_id]).fetchone()
if exists:
    pass
```